# How to find string position php

Tags: php, string

I want to get the position of 'ja' in each of the words in $string, but its not working. what am i doing wrong?

```
<?php
$offset = 0;

$find = 'ja';
$find_length = strlen($find);

$string = 'jasim jasmin jassir';

while ($string_position = strpos($string, $find, $offer)) {
echo $find.' found at '.$string_position.'<br>';
$offset = $string_position + $find_length;
}
?>
```

Comment: Use [`strpos()`](http://in1.php.net/strpos#107678) recursively from the example shown.

Comment: Check your variables' names (`$offer` is not `$offset`).

Comment: as @meze said: http://prntscr.com/3clzrm

Comment: changed to offset stil not working :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change the variable name to `$offset`
2. strpos may return 0 and `while` will treat it as false

So replace your while statement with:

```
while (($string_position = strpos($string, $find, $offset)) !== false) {
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I read a tutorial on this, and he did not use !==false, why does his code work without that?

Comment: @user2088624 which tutorial? Probably because his string doesn't start with the substring you look for.

Comment: Ah now i understand, very appreciated. I will accept your answer when i can.

Answer (score 1):

try changing offest

```
<?php
$offset = 1;

$find = 'ja';
$find_length = strlen($find);

$string = 'jasim jasmin jassir';

while ($string_position = strpos($string, $find, $offset)) {
echo $find.' found at '.$string_position.'<br>';
$offset = $string_position + $find_length;
}
?>
// output :- ja found at 6
             ja found at 13
```

if you don't want to change offset use

```
$string = ' jasim jasmin jassir'; (without space not be jasim it's 'jasim )
```

then it will output 3

```
    ja found at 1
ja found at 7
ja found at 14
```

**OR** try to change your condition check

```
while (($string_position = strpos($string, $find, $offset)) !== false) {
```

Comment: With offset = 1, you miss the first occurence of 'ja'

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
            // stack overflow area
            
            $offset = 0;

            $find = 'ja';
            $find_length = strlen($find);

            $string = 'jasim jasmin jassir';
            if (strpos($string, $find) === false) {
                echo "not found";
            }
            else {
                while (strpos($string, $find, $offset) !== false) {
                    $string_position = strpos($string, $find, $offset);
                    echo $find.' found at '.$string_position.'<br>';
                    $offset = $string_position + $find_length;
                }
            }
?>
```

Little workaround,  but it apparently works.

Output:

> ja found at 0
>
> ja found at 6
>
> ja found at 13

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should code this way to find string positions

```
$positions = array();
$offset = -1;
while (($pos = strpos($string, $find, $offset+1)) !== false) {
    $positions[] = $offset;
}

$result = implode(', ', $positions);
```

print this result